# How to compare two timestamps in MySql?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, sql-update

The timestamp field is a `DATETIME` column in a format like `2012-03-19 00:23:14`. How can I compare two rows of timestamps and find the larger one?  The query below that I am using isn't working.

```
UPDATE report 1 status = 'time is larger' WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT ip_src, layer4_sport, timestamp FROM  
      (SELECT ip_src, layer4_sport, timestamp from report 1) AS tmpb  
   WHERE  report 1.layer4_sport = tmpb.layer4_sport 
   AND report 1.ip_src = tmpb.ip_src  
   AND  report 1.timestamp > tmpb.timestamp 
   GROUP BY ip_src, layer4_sport,  timestamp HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Comment: What type are your 'timestamp' columns? I ask because if they are TIMESTAMP or DATETIME, the `>` operator should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks God, the query is OK now.

The missing was SET syntax after table name, and also GROUP BY syntax should be omitted from EXISTS.

```
UPDATE report 1 SET status = 'time is larger' WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT ip_src, layer4_sport, timestamp FROM  
  (SELECT ip_src, layer4_sport, timestamp from report 1) AS tmpb  
   WHERE  report 1.layer4_sport = tmpb.layer4_sport 
   AND report 1.ip_src = tmpb.ip_src  
   AND  report 1.timestamp > tmpb.timestamp)
```

Comment: The God who creates and inspires us.

Answer (score 8):

You can try use an if statement to validate if the A timestamp is greater than B timestamp.

```
select if(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-02-01 00:00:00') > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-01-01 00:00:00'), true, false)
```

Comment: I have changed my query, but still have the same problem, status isn't changed 
UPDATE report 1 status = 'time is larger' WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT ip_src, layer4_sport, timestamp FROM  
(SELECT ip_src, layer4_sport, timestamp from report 1) AS tmpb  
WHERE  report 1.layer4_sport = tmpb.layer4_sport 
AND report 1.ip_src = tmpb.ip_src  
AND  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('report 1.timestamp') > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('tmpb.timestamp') 
GROUP BY ip_src, layer4_sport HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)

Comment: check the table in this image, if u want.
http://filaty.com/i/1204/11946/Untitled.jpg

Comment: I think the problem is the EXISTS statement, try to use a IN statement.

In the subquery now you only need return the identifier of row that will be update

Comment: How can I use IN statement?!! The condition in subquery should be achieved and as I think it is only can be with EXISTS statement. Anyway, if you can help me to change the query and make it running without EXISTS, please write it down for me. Thanks

Comment: note when I remove every think related to timestamp, the updating will work just fine!

Comment: Try this:

    UPDATE report 1 status = 'time is larger' WHERE cid in (
    SELECT cid
    FROM report
    JOIN report as _tmp ON(report.layer4_sport = _tmp.layer4_sport AND report.ip_src = _tmp.ip_src)
    WHERE if(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(report.date) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(_tmp.date), 1, 0) = 1)

Comment: After changing to this UPDATE report.cid status = 'time is larger' WHERE report.cid in ( SELECT report.cid FROM report JOIN report as _tmp ON(report.layer4_sport = _tmp.layer4_sport AND report.ip_src = _tmp.ip_src) WHERE if(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(report.date) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(_tmp.date), 1, 0) = 1). It says "You can't specify target table 'report' for update in FROM clause". Any help please?

Comment: To perform an update in same table, first is necessary create a temporary table.

 UPDATE report.cid status = 'time is larger' WHERE report.cid in ((from (SELECT report.cid FROM report JOIN report as _tmp ON(report.layer4_sport = _tmp.layer4_sport AND report.ip_src = _tmp.ip_src) WHERE if(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(report.date) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(_tmp.date), 1, 0) = 1) as _tmp). For more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 2):

try the  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` functions to compare two timestamps.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp